# DefaultDataSource.getConnection(userID, password) Failing

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-was

I am working on WAS 6.1 to WAS 8.5.5 migration project (migrating JDK 1.5 to 1.7 as well ) and facing Database connectivity issue while switching project on WAS 8.5.5.

```
connection = defaultDataSource.getConnection(userID, password); Failing
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied DSRA0010E: SQL State = 72000, Error Code = 1,017
```

DataSource get Connection(userID, password)  - connection is getting proper when we pass DB connection user ID and Password (Which we used in JAAS - J2C authentication data at server).
But failing when we pass portal user ID and password.
**Same code is working on WAS 6.1 without any exception.**

**Getting proper connection with DataSource. getConnection() Method on WAS 8.5.5** 
The same code working in a different environment, but in this case when I call getConnection(userID, password) I get an exception. The datasource is WAS has the proper authentication alias set and when the connection is tested it works OK from the WAS side

I have used OJDBC6.jar (odbc4.1 which is supporting to WAS 8.5.5 ) but it application referring DataSource object from rt.jar of JRE lib.

Could you please guide me resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the scope of the Datasource? If possible, could you attach or provide the security.xml file and resources.xml from the scope of the datasource. It sounds like their is a sync issue between the security.xml and the information presented in the Admin console.

Please note, the test connection may provide different results depending on the scope of the datasource.

**Data source scope JVM where the test connection operation occurs**
**Cell**                manager process
**Node**                Node agent process (of the relevant node)
**Cluster**             Node agent for each node that contains a cluster member
**Server**              Server; if the server is unavailable, the test connection    operation is retried in the node agent for the node that contains the application server.

If you have a cluster scoped datasource, the test connection is really being performed at the node agent. Thus, a failure at the server level, possibly in your case, isn't being test.

Source: [Knowledge Center](https://ibm.biz/BdXjSH)

For resolution, I would suggest stopping the JVMs and performing a manually sync using the syncNode command.